# Complex and Customized SQL Join Conditions with Wildcard

Tags: python, mysql, sql, join, hive

I have two tables, one small (~ 6K rows) and the other big (~ 3M rows)

Table one looks like

```
## Table 1
-----------------------------------
| colA | colB | colC | ... | colZ |
-----------------------------------
| vA_1 |  *   | vC_1 | ... |  *   |
|  *   |  *   | vC_1 | ... | vZ_1 |
| vA_2 | vB_1 | vC_2 | ... | vZ_2 |
...
```

Table two looks like

```
## Table 2
-----------------------------------------
| colA | colB | colC | ... | colZ | ... |
-----------------------------------------
| vA_1 | vB_1 | vC_1 | ... | vZ_1 | ... |
| vA_1 | vB_1 | vC_2 | ... | vZ_2 | ... |
| vA_2 | vB_2 | vC_3 | ... | vZ_2 | ... |
...
```

So we want to "join" the two tables together based on all columns colA, colB, ..., colZ where wild card (*) will match anything. For example, for the very first row of table one.

```
-----------------------------------
| colA | colB | colC | ... | colZ |
-----------------------------------
| vA_1 |  *   | vC_1 | ... |  *   |
```

It should be able to match only the first row within table two, because colA, and colC are matched and any other columns can be any value, as represented as wild card in the first table.

```
## Table 2
-----------------------------------------
| colA | colB | colC | ... | colZ | ... |
-----------------------------------------
| vA_1 | vB_1 | vC_1 | ... | vZ_1 | ... |  √
| vA_1 | vB_1 | vC_2 | ... | vZ_2 | ... |  X
| vA_2 | vB_2 | vC_3 | ... | vZ_2 | ... |  X 
...
```

We wanted to construct some dynamic optional join like

```
if colA is *
    then join on colB, colC, ..
if colB is * 
    then join on colA, colC, ..
if colA is * and colB is *
    then join on colC, ...
...
```

We realized that the condition can grow exponentially (pretty much all the combinations at the order of factorial) as the number of columns grow. Hence, I am wondering if there a solution within SQL that can handle this kind of join.

I am also open to other solutions like customized code in Python or MapReduce, Spark.

Comment: Go back to the drawing board and normalize.. "The maximum number of tables that can be referenced in a single join is 61. This includes a join handled by merging derived tables and views in the FROM clause into the outer query block" source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/joins-limits.html

Comment: "We wanted to construct some dynamic optional join like" Not possible in SQL annyway..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this do what you want?

```
SELECT *
       FROM table1 t1
            INNER JOIN table2 t2
                       ON (t2.cola = t1.cola
                            OR t1.cola = '*')
                          AND (t2.colb = t1.colb
                                OR t1.colb = '*')
                          ...
                          AND (t2.colz = t1.colz
                                OR t1.colz = '*');
```

(Assuming that there are no `NULL`s as the sample data suggests. If there were any, they may need a special treatment depending on what you define as a match in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

It's a long `JOIN` but I guess it will work:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
  from table1 t1
  join table2 t2
     on (t1.cola = '*' or t1.cola = t2.cola)
    and (t1.colb = '*' or t1.colb = t2.colb)
    ...    
    and (t1.colz = '*' or t1.colz = t2.colz)
```

If you have wildcards `*` in table2 then the query becomes a little bit more complex:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
  from table1 t1
  join table2 t2
     on (t1.cola = '*' or t2.cola = '*' or t1.cola = t2.cola)
    and (t1.colb = '*' or t2.colb = '*' or t1.colb = t2.colb)
    ...    
    and (t1.colz = '*' or t2.colz = '*' or t1.colz = t2.colz)
```

Comment: I would begin with the second query. Because OP suggest the `*` is on table1. and make the query2 the exception

Comment: Good catch. Modified accordingly.